# Trying to run a word count hadoop on visual studio code and have saved it as a ps1 extension but function not running on powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

[VS CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgzb2.jpg)

```
Write-Host "Getting the context of your profile on Microsoft Azure..." -ForegroundColor Green 
$context = Get-AzContext

if ($null -eq $context) { Connect-AzAccount }

$context

$subscription = "5054f72b-16ed-4894-8bf5-fe7ad8fa20e3" 
$resourceGroupName = "BUS5WB" 
$clusterName = "bus5wb-hydra-s1-2022"

Write-Host "Selecting the subscription the HDInsight cluster is on..." -ForegroundColor Green 
Select-AzSubscription $subscription

Write-Host "Logging into the HDInsight cluster..." -ForegroundColor Green 
$cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter the HDInsight cluster HTTP user credential:" 

$wordCountJobDefinition = New-AzHDInsightMapReduceJobDefinition     -JarFile "/example/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar" -ClassName "wordcount"     -Arguments "/example/data/20450461/2Star.txt", ` "/example/data/20450461/2Star"

#Submit the job to the cluster 
Write-Host "Start the MapReduce job..." -ForegroundColor Green 
$wordCountJob = Start-AzHDInsightJob     -ClusterName $clusterName -JobDefinition $wordCountJobDefinition     -HttpCredential $cred -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

#Wait for the job to complete 
Write-Host "Wait for the job to complete..." -ForegroundColor Green 
Wait-AzHDInsightJob     -ClusterName $clusterName -JobId $wordCountJob.JobId ` -HttpCredential $cred
```

**THIS IS THE ERROR ON POWERSHELL**
[POWERSHELL ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PIGy.jpg)

```
Start the MapReduce job...
Start-AzHDInsightJob: C:\Users\20450461\Documents\2Star.ps1:48:17
Line |
  48 |  $wordCountJob = Start-AzHDInsightJob `
     |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

Wait for the job to complete...
Wait-AzHDInsightJob: C:\Users\20450461\Documents\2Star.ps1:58:12
Line |
  58 |      -JobId $wordCountJob.JobId `
     |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot bind argument to parameter 'JobId' because it is null.
```

Comment: People are much more likely to help you if you paste the text into your question rather than just a link to a picture. This feels like you put almost no effort into getting help, but expect us to put in effort to help you.

Comment: Wasn't my intention at all. This was my first question here so still trying to figure out how it works. My bad

Comment: The first error here is different than the error in the picture. This implies that you don't have access to run the job, so the job doesn't start and that causes the second error because there's no job to reference.